# How to get all foreign keys information from derby db?

Tags: database, derby

In SQL I would normaly get foreign keys information like so...

```sql
SELECT
    TABLE_SCHEMA as fromSchema,
    TABLE_NAME as fromTable,
    COLUMN_NAME as fromColumn,
    REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA as toSchema,
    REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME as toTable,
    REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME as toColumn
FROM information_schema.key_column_usage col
where REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME is not null
  and REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME is not null
  and REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA is not null
```

But how can I get the same informations from DERBY database?
I don't know how to get informations for columns `toColumn` and `fromColumn`???
I scanned whole derby documentation but I have no clue how to get name of foreign key column.

```sql
select FS.SCHEMANAME as "fromScheme",
       FT.TABLENAME  as "fromTable",
       TS.SCHEMANAME as "toScheme",
       TT.TABLENAME  as "toTable"
       -- How to get toColumn???
       -- How to get fromColumn???
from sys.SYSFOREIGNKEYS FK
         join SYS.SYSCONSTRAINTS S0 on FK.CONSTRAINTID = S0.CONSTRAINTID
         join SYS.SYSCONSTRAINTS S1 on FK.KEYCONSTRAINTID = S1.CONSTRAINTID
         join sys.SYSTABLES FT on S0.TABLEID = FT.TABLEID
         join sys.SYSSCHEMAS FS on FS.SCHEMAID = S0.SCHEMAID
         join sys.SYSTABLES TT on S1.TABLEID = TT.TABLEID
         join sys.SYSSCHEMAS TS on TS.SCHEMAID = S1.SCHEMAID;
```

## In response to Lajos Arpad (2* comment)

```sql
create schema test;
CREATE TABLE test.Course
(
    id   INTEGER     NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),
    name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT primary_key PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE test.Student
(
    id        INTEGER     NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),
    name      VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    surname   VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    faculty   VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    course_id INTEGER     NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT student_pk PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT student_fk FOREIGN KEY (course_id) REFERENCES test.course
);

select
    '----------SYS CONSTRAINTS---------------',
    C.*,
    '----------SYS FOREIGN KEYS---------------',
    F.*,
    '----------SYS CONGLOMERATES---------------',
    CON.*,
    '----------SYS TABLES---------------',
    T.*,
    '----------SYS SCHEMAS---------------',
    SC.*
from SYSCONSTRAINTS C
join SYS.SYSFOREIGNKEYS F on C.CONSTRAINTID = F.CONSTRAINTID
join sys.SYSCONGLOMERATES CON on CON.CONGLOMERATEID = F.CONGLOMERATEID
join sys.SYSTABLES T on T.TABLEID = CON.TABLEID
join sys.SYSSCHEMAS SC on SC.SCHEMAID = CON.SCHEMAID;
```

Produces folowing results...
[image]

Comment: Usually a DBMS has a [data dictionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_dictionary) that stores meta-data about the [database] tables, their columns and constraints - including primary keys and foreign keys. Refer to the [_Derby system tables_](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.8/ref/index.html) section of the [Derby] documentation.

Comment: @Abra Yes I did but I could not figure it out, (i know how to do it in sqlite, mariadb, etc...) but derby I could not.

Comment: Would you consider using Java to retrieve the information? Namely method [getImportedKeys](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getImportedKeys(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) in [interface] `java.sql.DatabaseMetaData`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion I will try your suggestion over java, you are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In the `sys` database you have these fields:

- `sysconstraints.constraintid`
- `sysforeignkeys.constraintid`
- `sysforeignkeys.conglomerateid`
- `sysconglomerates.conglomerateid`
- `sysconglomerates.tableid`
- `systables.tableid`
- `systables.schemaid`
- `sysschemas.schemaid`
- `sysconstraints.schemaid`

Join these together, filter by `sysconstraints.type = 'F'` and choose the columns you are interested in.

Comment: In table `select * from sys.SYSCOLUMNS;` where is located column name, there are only REFERENCEID and thats it... On `select * from sys.SYSCONSTRAINTS where TYPE = 'F';` there is `TABLEID`, `CONSTRAINTNAME`, `SCHEMAID` which does not match with `REFERENCEID` I have no clue with what to join? I'm hitting my head for 5h now and still no clue for solution.

Comment: @UrošJarc Join `syscontstraints` with `sysforeignkeys` on `constraintid`, join with `sysconglomerates` via `sysforeignkeys.conglomerateid`, then `systables` via `tableid` and then `susschemas` via `schemaid`.

Comment: I can get constraint name but foreign key is nowere to be found, I have added to my original post my test schema and results of the sql that you recomend... If you solve me this issue I'm ready to transfer 50eu over paypal to you for your help.